# Twilio API Stats Calls to Retrieve Agent Average/Max/Total Hold Times?

Tags: twilio

Is there a REST statistics API call that can be made that would retrieve the average, max, etc. hold times for Twilio tasks, queues, or workers/agents?
I see statistics that can show a participant being on hold at the current time, but not for reportable statistics on hold times.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe you are looking for the [TaskQueue Statistics API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/taskqueue-statistics).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've looked at this before, but it doesn't seem to return any stats related to the hold time of a task/call.

Comment: Does the `AvgTaskAcceptanceTime` not help? It is "The average time (in seconds) from Task creation to reservation acceptance while in this TaskQueue." Or the `WaitDurationUntilAccepted` ("The wait duration stats (avg, min, max, total) for tasks that were accepted while in this TaskQueue").

Comment: The metric I'm looking for is after the reservation acceptance, if an agent begins talking to a customer, and then the agent puts the customer on hold part way through to discuss with other agents, or research something, then resumes the call, how long that mid conversation "hold time" was. 

In the documentation, it's the section "putting a call on hold":
https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/contact-center-blueprint/call-control-concepts

Comment: Oh, for a user that is on hold as part of a conference? That functionality is outside of TaskRouter itself, so is not collected as part of the stats. And there is not an API for stats on lengths of time callers are put on hold like this. I would recommend you record this yourself, by starting and stopping timers when you trigger the REST API to put the user on/off hold.

Comment: Great, thanks, that's what I was looking to confirm. We recently also reached out to Twilio, who had the following response that appears to be a similar suggestion:
We do not have a specific API for the purpose, but what you could use is a status callback https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent to get an event when a "hold" is initiated and compare it with a "join" event. The timestamps between the two would help with what you are trying to achieve.